# How to send invoice after shipment e-mail?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, shipping, email, invoice

I am looking to set up the transactional e-mails in a way that goes order confirmation (after checkout), shipment (manually) the invoice after shipment.

This is so that I can check stock before invoicing the customer.

At the moment invoices send automatically after the order along with the order confirmation e-mail.

Is there a way to change this so that invoices can be sent manually?

The site is running on Magento Community Edition v1.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento invoices are created once you have received payment. So if you are using an automatic payment gateway and have it set to authorize and capture it will automatically create an invoice. However, if you set it to only authorize the payment you will manually have to capture the payment hence manually create an invoice.

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: I am using PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution (Includes Express Checkout) and the payment action is set to authorize, however, it still invoices automatically if it is set to authorise of if set to sale. Am I looking at the wrong setting here?

Comment: So if you have it set to Authorization a invoice should not be created.                                                ----Set Payment Action to one of the following:
Authorization: With this payment action, there is a delay between the time the payment is approved, and when the funds are withdrawn from the customer’s account. A hold is put on the funds, but the amount is not withdrawn from the customer’s account until the funds are “captured” by the merchant.
Sale: The amount of the purchase is authorized and withdrawn from the customer’s account at the same time.